# Hungarian/Bulgarian characters from CSV file end up garbled in PHP

Tags: php, csv, character-encoding

I'm trying to import a CSV file which looks something like this:

> "source   "," destination "
>
> férfi-/ruházat-Öltöny,"   férfi-/ruházat-blézer_zakó",

Note that this is just a sample of the CSV, not the whole CSV.

The way I'm reading the file is pretty straight forward:

```
$line = fgets($this->fileHandle) ;
$line = mb_convert_encoding($line , 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($line));
```

Where `$this->fileHandle` is just a resource pointing to the file opened using `fopen`. So nothing too special there.

I want to do some string manipulation on the strings inside the CSV. I can import it just fine.

When I read from the file, either using `fgets`, `fread` or whatever other function I can think if I end up with garbled text.

Something along the lines of this:

[image]

So far I've tried `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8")`, to `ISO-8859-2` and a few other encodings. Nothing worked.

I've also tried `mb_convert_encoding($line , 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($line))` where `$line` is the line read from the csv.
Again, nothing. Still garbled text.

Next I assumed it may be something from my OS. I' using MAC with a docker instance on Ubuntu.

Using High Sierra v10.13.4 on mac

A `locale` command in the terminal gives me:

```
LANG="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

As far as the docker instance:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

# locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

So everything seems to be fine in that regard.

---

I've also tried an online PHP interpreter and that works fine. So clearly the issue is on my side.

To be honest I have no idea where the issue lies.

Any pointing in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the encoding of this `CSV` file?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

I had to `ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");`. The default was an empty string.

I have no idea how it worked without it so far, I assume it has some sort of fallback encoding.

Either way, I hope this helps anybody else who gets stuck on this.

Comment: Rather than depend on a default, you simple have to read a text file with the character encoding that was used to write it.